# Selenium Grid (v4) session "Duration" goes beyoung 10days

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-docker, docker-selenium

We have a Selenium Grid setup via docker on an ubuntu machine with the following settings

```
# To execute this docker-compose yml file use `docker-compose -f docker-compose-v3.yml up`
# Add the `-d` flag at the end for detached execution
# To stop the execution, hit Ctrl+C, and then `docker-compose -f docker-compose-v3.yml down`
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.5.0-20221017
    shm_size: 8gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=200
      - SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true
      - SE_SCREEN_WIDTH=1920
      - SE_SCREEN_HEIGHT=1080

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.5.0-20221017
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
```

Some sessions on this grid "hang".
[image]

Also, I can not connect to the session to close them manually. Only restart of the Grid helps.
I know that some of the UI tests may not do a proper cleanup, but still, Selenium Grid docker docs say that timeout is 300 sec by default
[image]

Anyone experienced the same problem & can suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing such issues as well. This might happen if you do not use `quit()` in your tests or it is bypassed due to some exceptions.

So that leads to the session remains open.

I do not know why timeout does not kill the session automatically. Probably it is worth raising issue at Selenium github project. But as a workaround you could use [DELETE](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#delete-session) query to the hub

So no need to restart the entire grid.

Comment: This is interesting. But I don't see an API to get all sessions. So how would I know which session hangs?

Comment: Try  get status https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-status